# Is the copy constructor called when an object is passed by reference?

Tags: c++, constructor

When a class object is passed by value to any function, the copy constructor is called to create a local object and the destructor is called when the object is returned.
But, will copy constructor be called if the object reference is passed?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and explain what behavior you saw and what you expected

Comment: Passing by reference causes no copying, therefore the copy-constructor should not be called.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: No, it will not.

Comment: C++ doesn't have "class objects".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nope, it won't be called.**

A reference is an alias, that is, another name for **an already existing variable** and not for a copy.

Take a look at this example:

```
class Line {
public:
   int getLength( void ){}
   // simple constructor
   Line(  ){
      cout<<"constructor"<<endl;
   }   
   // copy constructor          
   Line( const Line &obj){
      cout<<"copy cts\n";
   }  
};

void callR(Line& l){
   cout<<"call by ref\n";
}
void callC(Line l){
   cout<<"call by copy\n";
}


int main() {

   Line line;
   cout<<"before call by reference\n";
   callR(line);
   cout<<"before call by copy\n";
   callC(line);
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
constructor ->  Line line;
before call by reference
call by ref 
before call by copy
copy cts
call by copy
```

As you can see copy constructor is not called when an object is passed by reference. Think of a reference as a pointer.